# Background color in forms

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a background color to the HTML form tag, but it doesn't work?! I thought it was a simple task!

```
#form {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your HTML code? Also, what browser(s)?

Comment: Hmmm, that will be to much code. Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: does your form actually have the id="form" set? if not, you need to remove the sharp (#)

Comment: you've asked 33 questions and never cast a single vote, I'd say any amount of code is too much for you to post

Comment: Sorry, thas was an typing error I made. I have also tried without the #

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we just see the HTML code of your form? Maybe there's a class you're using that conflicts with your #form declaration.

Also, if you want the "form block" to have a background, put it inside a div and background it.

If you want to give a background to the form inputs, you should give a style to the input objects

```
#form input{
  background-color: #000;
}

#form input .submit{ ... }

#form label { ... }
```

And so on.

Comment: OK, I try to make a wrapping div around it!

Answer (score 5):

You can use an inline style:

```
<form style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
<input type="submit" value="ClickMe" >
</form>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/b34b3/)

Comment: That is an inline style, which does work, but it is a good idea to keep your CSS in the style sheet so it is not spread out all over your HTML and thus easier to change.

Answer (score 3):

You should post the HTML content, but if you want to set the style sheet for the form "tag", you should not use #. instead do something like:

```
form {background:#000000;}
```

"#" is applied for the elements with the appended id, and the style sheet you have written works for an element like
    < div id="form" >etc...< /div >

Answer (score 1):

Here, what you need to do is specify a class in the HTML tag, and from there, you can make changes as you wish in the CSS.

HTML:

```
<form class="My-form">
```

.
.
.

CSS:

`.My-form { background-color: #f0f0f0; }`

React User:
If you are using React, you should use the className attribute to specify the class for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The form had fieldset tags in it, and those had the style `float:left`. This caused the background-color not to be rendered. Without the float it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want no background in your form then set the background to `none`:

```
<form style="background:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

For background colors in a form, notify the form control in the form tag and provide this form field in the style tag as shown below.

```
form {
  background-color: #FFC;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"notify the form control"*? Can you elaborate (please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60395977/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar), not here in comments).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this on CodePen. If the input tags are wrapped in a fieldset within the form, then adding a background-color to the fieldset works perfectly. Like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

fieldset {
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: none;
}

input, label {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <label for="">Enter email</label>
    <input type="text" email="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```