# <input> type color change not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of input type. It is working fine in firefox but not in chrome. My style is being overridden by user agent stylesheet.
Is there any way by which i can override **user agent stylesheet** for chrome.

```
.form-list input, textarea {
  background-color : #F5F5F2;
}
```

Comment: try to use input[type="text"], textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: Also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could use !important but this prevents custom stylesheets from taking effect and is kind of a bad practice.

I would suggest making sure your rules are more specifc so listing the div's for example that are surrounding the control.

```
div > div > .form-list { background-color: #F5F5F2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code should work as it is, As it works fine for me :

Can you please post your code so I can take a look?

There is similar question you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786963/background-color-in-forms).

```css
.form-list input, textarea {
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-list">
    <input type="text" name="t" />
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found one solution which is working. Hope  it will help others too.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #F5F5F2 inset;
}
```